# Need to add vertical separator (a line of 1px width) for my list items in qml listListView(horizontal)

Tags: qml

I have given rectangle within the delegate. This resulted in separator lines which are part of list items itself(which is not expected). Please suggest on how to get the separators(line) independent of list items.
If I write rectangle out of delegate, only only line is drawn.

The purpose is to add a line between buttons(list items) in buttonbar.
My code is:

```
ChinoListCatalog {
    objectName : "alertButtonBar"
    id: alertButtonBar
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    width: 730
    height: 66

    orientation: ListView.Horizontal

    delegate: AlertButton { //a separate file which returns buttons  
        id: alertButton
        width: 100
        onSignalButtonAction: alertButtonBar.onSignalButtonAction(index, action)

        Rectangle { // Separator
            colour : "white"
            height: parent.height
            visible : true
        }
    }
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    pressDelay: 100
}
```

Comment: Something's wong with indentation, haven't you forgot to put an empty line before it?

Comment: What is the problem with it beeing included in the delegate that you try to solve?

Comment: The separator is supposed to be between two buttons. The separator line overlaps with the button it belongs to. I want it to appear between buttons(list items)

Comment: @user2436719 Where to put empty line??

Comment: @DumbDeveloper: To help us, helping you, always try to post a minimal but working code example. Instead of the `ChinoListCatalog` a `ListModel` and instead of the `AlertButton` a simple `Rectangle` would be probably sufficient to make your case. However it would allow us to copy your code and run it, to see what you've got.
The signal-handling and behavior-stuff - I guess - are also of little relevance to your problem, aren't they?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask As you are new, this might be a good reading for you to get a good start on this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this? It is a vertical ListView, but it should be easy to adapt it to a vertical one. You can also omit the line if it is the last element (`height: (index === lm.count - 1 ? 0 : 1)`)

```
ListModel {
    id: lm

    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
    ListElement {}
}

ListView {
    model: lm

    width: 100
    height: 200

    delegate: Item {
        width: 100
        height: 42
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.topMargin: 1
            anchors.bottomMargin: 1
            id: butt
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: index
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            height: 1
            color: 'green'
            anchors {
                left: butt.left
                right: butt.right
                top: butt.bottom
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is basically, not to use the button as the root element for the delegate but a seperate Item in which you can arrange everything as you want it to appear.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.
Please do not forget to check this answer if it is what you were looking for.

Greetings
-m-

Comment: Hi derM, Thanks a lot for this input. This is exactly what I wanted. I used it for vertical list view scenario. Thank you very much for the help. Appreciate it :-)

Comment: You are welcome! I'd appreciate it, if you might click on the 'tick' next to my answer ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
    ListModel {
        id: lm
        ListElement {} ListElement {} ListElement {} ListElement {}
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        width : 200
        height : 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent

    ListView {
        model: lm
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: 400
        height: 50

        orientation : ListView.Horizontal
        delegate: Item {
            width: 51
            height: 60
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.rightMargin: 1
                anchors.topMargin : 10
                id: butt
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                width : 50
                height : 50
                color :'blue'
                radius : 10
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id : leftOne
                    height: 50
                    width: 1
                    color: 'red'
                    visible : (index < 3) //last element in the list should not have separator
                    anchors {
                        left: butt.right
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //spacing : 2
    }
 }
```